# Como chamar uma variável do JS para um h1 do HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu tenho este pequeno [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/45rz6rup/2/) para exemplificar o meu problema.

**HTML**

```
  <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>

    <h1>"I have " + count + " list items"</h1>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var count = 0;

$("li").each(function(){
      count++;      
    });
```

A variável `count` do JavaScript vai ter o número de `li`'s da `ul`.

Como é que é que faço para aparecer, no `h1` do HTML, a variável `count` ?

Comment: Não preferes imprimir todo o texto no `h1`? Alias, até acho que é a única solução

Comment: Aparecer todo o texto como assim? Eu queria que aparecesse: " I have `count` list items"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ou você preenche o `<h1>` inteiro, assim:

```
var count = 0;

$("li").each(function(){
    count++;      
});
$('h1').html("I have " + count + " list items");
```

Ou cria um span lá dentro pra guardar só o `count`:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>

<h1>I have <span>0</span> list items</h1>
```

```
var count = 0;

$("li").each(function(){
    count++;      
});
$('h1 span').html(count);
```

E, como disse o @KaduAmaral, nem é necessário o `each` para fazer essa contagem, dá pra resolver tudo numa linha, pegando o tamanho (`length`) da coleção de `<li>`s:

```
$('h1 span').html( $('li').length );
```

Se quiser fazer em JavaScript puro em vez de jQuery, também é bem simples:

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var span = document.querySelector('h1 span');
span.innerHTML = lis.length;
```

Comment: Uma melhoria seria nem utilizar o each, usar só um `$("li").length` mesmo, mas não sei como realmente está o contexto do autor...

Comment: @KaduAmaral qual vai ser a principal diferença se eu usar o `length` em vez do `each`?

Comment: @msm.oliveira, o `length`, é uma variável que já contem o valor pronto, ou seja, você não precisa "perder tempo" percorrendo todos os itens para saber quantos tem.
http://jsfiddle.net/g0z1j3n7/

Comment: @msm.oliveira O KaduAmaral tem razão, editei a resposta mostrando um exemplo com o `length`.

Comment: @bfavaretto depois de ver o comentario do KaduAmaral vi que o resultado era o mesmo. só queria perceber a diferença. mas já percebi. obrigado aos dois

Comment: @msm.oliveira Também acrescentei uma alternativa em JS puro, caso você queira abrir mão do jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Uma possível forma de solução é enviares o código/texto que queres para o teu `h1`:

```js
var count = 0;

$("li").each(function(){
      count++;      
    });

$('h1').empty().append("I have " + count + " list items");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>

<h1>"I have " + count + " list items"</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode fazer isto desta forma:

```
var count = 0;
$("li").each(function(){
  count++;      
});
$( "#varh1").html("I have "+count+" list items");
```

No qual varh1 é o ID do elemento h1